# gremlin how to set scriptevaluationtimeout 0

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I want to set scriptevaluationtimeout 0.
I'm using apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.4.9.
and I want to use gremlin-python.

Comment: What are you planning to do? scriptevaluationtimeout as 0 will cause every query to fail. Is that what you want? Also apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console uses groovy internally and is different from gremlin-python. Are you looking for an answer to both?

Comment: 0 is the configuration that will disable the timeout all together.

Answer (score 3):

As the question above noted, it's not quite clear whether you mean Gremlin Console or gremlin-python so I will just answer both ways. For Gremlin Console, the preferred method for remote connections is to issue this command:

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml 
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :remote config timeout none
```

The above is detailed in [this section](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-console) of the Reference Documentation. For gremlin-python you can configure per request timeouts as described [here for scripts](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_per_request_settings_2):

```
result_set = client.submit('g.V().repeat(both()).times(100)', result_options={'evaluationTimeout': 0})
```

or [here for bytecode](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python-connecting):

```
vertices = g.with_('evaluationTimeout', 0).V().out('knows').toList()
```

Comment: thanks. 
gremlin> :remote config timeout none
==>Remote timeout is disabled
Script evaluation exceeded the configured 'scriptEvaluationTimeout' threshold of 30000 ms or evaluation was otherwise cancelled directly for request [graph.traversal().withComputer().V().has('lat', 34.66494274048).shortestPath().with(ShortestPath.target, __.has('lat', 34.66561185416)).with(ShortestPath.distance, 'cost')]

Comment: I think so..
I set the remote config timeout none , and above traverse Failed(scriptEvaluationTimeout).
I will try the same query by python-gremlin.

Comment: What graph database are you using?

Comment: I use doker image tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.9

Comment: :remote config timeout 3000000 worked.but evaluationTimeout.

Comment: related novice question on best practices for setting proper timeouts and retries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65942700/how-to-make-gremlin-python-driverremoteconnection-to-have-timeout-and-retry-limi

Comment: I'm not sure your Python bytecode works. I've been initializing my `g` like this: 

from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
g: GraphTraversalSource = traversal().withRemote(
        DriverRemoteConnection(GRAPH_DB_URL, 'g',
                               username=GRAPH_DB_USER,
                               password=GRAPH_DB_PASSWORD)).with_('evaluationTimeout', 0)

But I still get timeout errors.